# KeyError: 'url_ids' - Odoo Module mrigation from v8 to v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this class:

```
class WizardUrlSeniat(models.TransientModel):

_name = "wizard.seniat.url"

url1 = fields.Char(
    string='URL1', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url1(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' fiscal information from partner')
url2 = fields.Char(
    string='URL2', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url2(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' retention rate from partner (RIF)')
url3 = fields.Char(
    string='URL3', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' retention rate from partner (CI or Passport)')

@api.multi
def _get_url(self): 
    """ Get seniat web page
    """
    url = self.env['seniat.url']
    url_ids = url.search([]) 
    if len(url_ids) > 1:
        url.unlink.self.env.url_ids[1:] 
    url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse() 
    return url_obj 

@api.multi
def _get_url1(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 


@api.multi
def _get_url2(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.url_seniat

@api.multi
def _get_url3(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.url_seniat2
```

When I click on `url3` from a menuitem, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1101, in default_get
defaults[name] = field.default(self)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 41, in <lambda>
default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 69, in _get_url3
url_obj = self._get_url() #(self.env.cr) 
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 53, in _get_url
url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse() 
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 752, in __getitem__
return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 170, in __getitem__
return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'url_ids'
```

The errors are precisely on `default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),` from `url3` field.
On `url_obj = self._get_url()` from `_get_url3()`, and `url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse()` from first method `_get_url`.

This is a module I'm migrasting from v8 to v10, It's almost complete, but there is something that I don't see here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line of your code:

```
    url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse()
```

what is **url_ids**, if it is some model name, shouldn't it follow the dot convention (not that it matters) like it should be **url.ids** and keep in mind the **self.env** takes a model name as key.

if you are trying to browse the **url_ids** retrieved through search from here:

```
url = self.env['seniat.url']
url_ids = url.search([])
```

then you should do:

```
browse_records = self.env['seniat.url'].browse(url_ids)
```

which will return the browse records for those **url_ids**

Comment: Super awesome! Thanks :D

Comment: Sorry but that is just wrong. `search` is returning a `RecordSet` (no `browse_record`s in the new API anymore!) already, no need to call browse after a search.

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether the **object 'url_ids'** is correctly defined in your module. Its throwing error when you try to browse that object.

Hope this helps.